# Any other quick way to find the remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find 
$$19^{13}\operatorname{mod}(2537).$$

Is there quick way to find the remainder?

Comment: $$(19,43)=1=(19,59), 2537=43\cdot59$$

Comment: Expounding on what Peter said, since $19$ is prime, only $1, 19, 19^2, 19^3, ..., 19^{13}$ divide $19^{13}$, and $19$ and any power of it does not divide $2537$.

Comment: @ Peter @ Eevee Trainer @ lab bhattacharjee Yes, my question is wrong because my calculation is incorrect. Now I know the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

- Write $19^{13}=(19^3)^4\cdot19$.
- Note that $19^3=6859\equiv-752\pmod{2537}$.
- Write $(-752)^4$ as $((-752)^2)^2$ and evaluate the inner bracket to simplify.

Comment: Please check my answer, is it correct answer?

Comment: Quite rather a PSQ, don't you think?

Comment: @amWhy They originally had some working but it was pointed out that it was wrong so they deleted it. However, they have provided their own correct answer below mine so I won't be too harsh about it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
19^3=6859&\equiv& 1785(\operatorname{mod}2537)\\
19^6=\left(19^3\right)^2\equiv (1785)^2=3186225&\equiv& 2290(\operatorname{mod}2537)\\
19^{12}=\left(19^6\right)^2\equiv (2290)^2 = 5244100&\equiv& 121(\operatorname{mod}2537)\\
19^{13}=19^{12}\cdot19&\equiv& 121\cdot 19=2299(\operatorname{mod}2537)
\end{eqnarray}

So the remainder is 2299. Is this correct answer?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint, @ TheSimpliFire.